# Unable to get Dynamically added textarea value on keypress

Tags: javascript, jquery

It was working fine all these while, just now I re-factor codes for other functions, now this silly problem occurs and I've no idea why this happens.

**Markup in jquery for textarea**

```
 +'<div class="ckit-container__ft" data-ckit-footer>'
            +'<form action="" class="ckit-composer-form">'
                +'<div class="ckit-composer">'
                    +'<textarea data-ckit-composer-textarea placeholder="Add your reply" autocomplete="off" name="message" class="form-control ckit-composer__textarea"></textarea>'
                +'</div>'
            +'</form>'       
        +'</div>
```

**Binding keypress event**

```
jQuery(function($){
jQuery('body').bind('keypress','[data-ckit-composer-textarea]',function(event)
{
console.log(jQuery('[data-ckit-composer-textarea]').val());//returns empty 
console.log(jQuery(this).val());//returns empty string
});
});
```

Since the HTML markup exist outside `$(function(){..})`, I even tried cloning the template and find the relevant attribute to replace but no luck.

```
var fullChatView = '<div class="ckit-container__ft" data-ckit-footer>'
                +'<form action="" class="ckit-composer-form">'
                    +'<div class="ckit-composer">'
                        +'<textarea data-ckit-composer-textarea placeholder="Add your reply" autocomplete="off" name="message" class="form-control ckit-composer__textarea"></textarea>'
                    +'</div>'
                +'</form>'       
            +'</div>';

var test = $(fullchatView).clone();//ReferenceError: fullchatView is not defined
var val = test.find('[data-ckit-composer-textarea]').val();
console.log(val);
```

Comment: what version are of jQuery are you using? you can use `.on()` for version 1.7 above

Comment: @guradio, where to use on? for keypress? But I should bind it first right?

Comment: yes use `jQuery('body').on('keypress','[data-ckit-composer-textarea]',function(event)
{` bind is for version less than 1.7 check [documentation here](http://api.jquery.com/bind/) `As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.`

Comment: Your use of `.bind()` is incorrect, it doesn't take a selector as its second argument. **Read the documentation.** If you're using the latest jQuery use `.on()`, otherwise use `.delegate()`. Either way, read the doco.

Comment: @guradio, tried on, still I'm not getting the textarea value on keypress..I tried hardcode some value into textarea, and on keypress that value are logged. But it's not detecting value that i'm tying into textarea..

Comment: can you check console for error or make a demo?

Comment: @guradio. for whatever reason I again, replaced console.log(jQuery('[data-ckit-composer-textarea]').val()); with console.log(jQuery(this).val()); and it works now.. And this solution only works with  'on' and not working with 'bind'

Comment: @guradio, can you post your answer just now, so that I may accept it?

Comment: In your first code example, just change `bind` to `on` and `keypress` to `keyup`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
jQuery('body').on('keypress','[data-ckit-composer-textarea]',function(event) { });
```

[Documentation](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

> As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

Answer (score 1):

In your first code example, change `.bind()` to [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) and use the [`keyup` event](https://api.jquery.com/keyup/), rather than the [`keypress` event](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/).

Try the following:

```
jQuery(function($) {
    // Note: The $ parameter passed in to this callback function
    // represents the jQuery object, so you can safely use $ inside
    // this function.
    $('body').on('keyup', '[data-ckit-composer-textarea]', function() {
        console.log($(this).val());
    });
});
```

When the [`keypress` event](https://api.jquery.com/keypress/) is fired, the value of the textarea has not yet been changed to include the pressed key.

Answer (score 0):

Try using 
[jQuery.parseHTML()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsehtml/)

where you do the clone

Comment: I prefer not to use cloning..can point out where the mistake lies?